# Is it possible to send push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging to flutter app when targetd devices are offline

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

> Blockquote

here i have to send some notifiaction to android & ios devices,
using flutter framework i had built an app when device internet
connectivity is also not available i have send notification message
to device also app is not running in background.

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications will reach the device once it comes back online, this is something not related to flutter or react native or whatever stack you are using. As long as you have the device endpoint (FCM) registered and you push to it

Answer (score 0):

The notifications won't reach the target device unless it has internet connectivity.

> There are many devices that go offline, and some never come back online. Messages for applications on these devices will continue to be accepted by FCM, but will not be delivered unless the device comes back online.

Although there are multiple other factors that you should consider. You can read more about them in this Firebase blog.

[Life of a message](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/02/life-of-a-message.html)